# how to create a sub menu on laravel in template view?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder, submenu

i want to create a sub menu on my templates/master. i want all my process in there. i have table: `menu`, `role`, and `menu_role` (conatins many to many from menu and role).

i tried to select table menu through menu_role, because i want display menu according to its role. it success but there is no sub menu. i'm bad at query builder with relationship.

this is my `templates/master.blade.php` :

```
use App\MenuRole;
use App\Role;
use App\Menu;
use App\Admin;
use App\Operator;

$userCheck = Auth::user()->role_id;
$menus = MenuRole::with('menu')->where('role_id', $userCheck)->get();
```

and for the html, if there is no module on table menu i want to display this :

```
@foreach($menus as $menu)
    <li><a href="/{{ Auth::user()->role->role_name }}/{{ $menu->menu->route }}" target="{{ $menu->menu->target }}">{{ $menu->menu->title }}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

and if there is a `module`, i want to display this :

```
<li class="has-sub">
      <a class="js-arrow" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>{{ $menu->module }}</a>
      <ul class="navbar-mobile-sub__list list-unstyled js-sub-list">
          <li><a href="/{{ Auth::user()->role->role_name }}/{{ $menu->menu->route }}">{{ $menu->menu->title }}</a></li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

so the thing is, in table menu i have field `module`. this field will distinguish which ones have subMenu and which have no subMenu. and i want to `foreach` table menu. i have configure the model.

Answer (score 0):

Will a simple `@empty` condition suffice? When a Menu has the `module` field filled it shows one thing, otherwise the other.

```
@foreach ($menus as $menu)
    @empty($menu->menu->module)

    @else

    @endempty
@endforeach
```

If this does not solve your problem, could you please go into more detail about what you want it to look like?